# SQL update statement not working for 281 records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running these queries in DataGrip by Jetbrains

So the first query is for reseting the progression of a snapchat where snap_username = '0'. I run it and it says 281 records affects, great it worked? No.

```
UPDATE cache_items SET snap_username = NULL AND snap_processed_at = NULL AND snap_approved_at = NULL AND snap_result = 'waiting' WHERE LENGTH(snap_username) > 0
AND snap_username = '0';
```

This one still returns the original 281 records, after runn ing the first query multiple times, each time it saying 281 rows affected.

```
SELECT item, description, snap_username FROM cache_items WHERE LENGTH(snap_username) > 0
AND snap_username = '0';
```

Weirdly I'm not sure how it got to 0 originally - I'm guessing it was one of my seeders messing up.

snap_username is a varchar 255 datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
UPDATE cache_items
    SET snap_username = NULL,
        snap_processed_at = null,
        snap_approved_at = null,
        snap_result = 'waiting'
    WHERE LENGTH(snap_username) > 0 AND snap_username = '0';
```

Note that that `AND`s are replaced by `,`s.

Your code was parsed as:

```
set snap_username = (NULL AND snap_processed_at = null AND snap_approved_at = null AND snap_result = 'waiting')
```